# custom Copy Responder in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, copy, uiresponder

I have a webview in my application. I want to handle when user copies something from web view, my custom method - should be triggered. I have tried following.

I have placed following method in myViewCtr.m file

```
-(void)copy:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"hi ! Hello ");
}
```

But nothing working - what should I do to implement the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `-copy:` on the *responder*, not on the *controller*. So you need to subclass `UIWebView` and override `-copy:`.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ! I got something [here](http://www.mobileorchard.com/hold-and-copy-in-uikit/) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110731/implementing-iphones-copy-paste-controls-on-a-custom-view-uiview-subclass).

[Direct sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CopyPasteTile/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009040) from Apple itself.

[Theory](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW26) :)