# iPhone, I want to create a popup menu from my tab bar, but what are they call, like copy / paste?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'd like to create a popup menu, from my tab bar.
I've seen them, but I'm not sure what they called ?

Kind of like a speak bubble.

I think copy / paste is the sort of thing I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for the [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110731/implementing-iphones-copy-paste-controls-on-a-custom-view-uiview-subclass) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

That could be the UIActionSheet. You might want to give it a try.

```
//Your delegate for pressed buttons.
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
        //Your Action for pressed button.
    [actionSheet release];
}

//Declare a method to show your sheet
-(void)showActionSheet
{
    UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                           initWithTitle: @"Action Sheet Title" 
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                           destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete"
                           otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button1", @"Other Button2", nil];
    [menu showInView:self.view];
}
```

But you said "bubble", so that could also be the UIAlertView.

Try this:

```
-(void)showAlertView
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" 
                                                         message:@"This is the message that pops up in the bubble." 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad, you'd want UIPopoverController, but I think that on the iPhone the same sort of interactions are meant to be performed by a separate, full screen controller or by a UIActionSheet. There's no speech bubble on the iPhone such that I'm aware.

Comment: I think he means the little menu that comes up when you select or highlight text, UIPopoverController and UIActionSheet do different things.

Comment: Though they do different things, Apple appear to endorse the use of a UIActionSheet as the normal way to select options, appearing within a UIPopoverController on the iPad and as a normal action sheet on the iPhone. Hence the addition of showFromBarButtonItem:animated: to UIActionSheet.