# UIMenuController not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to create a custom UIMenuController and display it in my view. Here's my code:

```
UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *listMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"List" action:@selector(addList:)];

    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:listMenuItem]];
    [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 0, 0) inView:self.view];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    [listMenuItem release];
```

There are no errors or exceptions, but the menu controller just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to do three things:

1. You need to call [`-becomeFirstResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder) on the view or view controller.
2. Your view or view controller needs to implement [`-canBecomeFirstResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canBecomeFirstResponder) (returning `YES`).
3. Optionally, your view or view controller can implement [`-canPerformAction:action withSender:sender`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction:withSender:) to show/hide menu items on an individual basis.

Comment: This works really well in MonoTouch too--only things to be aware of is that the `CanBecomeFirstResponder` is a property override, and that you must assign a `UIMenuItem[]` array to the `UIMenuController.MenuItems` property.

Comment: Didn't work when I called `becomeFirstResponder` *on the view*. Calling it on the controller worked fine.

Comment: To make sure the call to becomeFirstResponder succeeds, you may check the BOOL it returns is YES. Otherwise you can expect the presentation of UIMenuController to fail.

Comment: I got this working on the _view_, as long as I implemented step 3 (not optional).

Comment: Implementing ` -canPerformAction` isn't optional.

Comment: I got it to work without step 3. The trick is that if you implement the selector (in the question: "addList"), then the ViewController will automatically return true for canPerformAction.

Comment: Overriding `- canBecomeFirstResponder` fixed my problem, thx.

Comment: Nice answer for saving my life.

Comment: "Your view or view controller needs to implement -canBecomeFirstResponder (returning YES).." That was a key to show it from UITableView header! Thanks! (I already called becomeFirstResponder() on that view)

Answer (score 25):

The answer mentions three things, but to be picky, there are six:

1. The menu handler must be a UIView. If it isn't, `-becomeFirstResponder` fails.
2. The menu handler must have `userInteractionEnabled = YES`
3. The menu handler must be in the view hierarchy and its `-window` property must be the same as the window for the view in the `inView:` argument.
4. You need to implement `-canBecomeFirstResponder` and return `YES`.
5. You need to call `[handler becomeFirstResponder]`, *before* `[menu setTargetRect:inView:]` is called, or the latter will fail.
6. You need to call `[menu setTargetRect:inView]` (at least once) and `[menu setMenuVisible:animated:]`.

In particular points 1-3 above got me. I wanted a custom menu handler class that was a `UIResponder` at first, which caused `-becomeFirstResponder` to return `NO`; then it was a `UIView`, which failed, then I tried making it a `UIButton` which worked, but only because `userInteractionEnabled` defaults to `YES` for buttons and `NO` for `UIView`s.

Answer (score 15):

`UIMenuController` is visible on any view only if the view is first responder and

`- (BOOL)canPerformAction` method returns `YES`

Hence if your menu controller is to be shown on button click, the first line in the button action should be `[self becomeFirstResponder]`. NOTE: here self is the view which will present the menus.

If your menus are to be shown on long press gesture, then add longPressGesture to the `UIView` and in the longpress event before writing

```
[menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 0, 0) inView:self.view];
[menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

write `[self becomeFirstResponder];`

Then follow the steps mentioned by OZ.

Comment: I tried this but its not working for me. As comment have limit I have created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054050/uimenucontroller-not-getting-displayed

Comment: Thanks, the targetRect did the trick for me. Weird because I have another almost identical class that works fine without it.

Answer (score 8):

The below is a full commented working example ...

View subclass header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MenuControllerSupportingView : UIView
{

}
@end
```

View subclass source file

```
#import "MenuControllerSupportingView.h"

@implementation MenuControllerSupportingView

//It's mandatory and it has to return YES then only u can show menu items..
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
  return YES;
}

-(void)MenuItemAClicked
{
  NSLog(@"Menu item A clicked");
}

-(void)MenuItemBClicked
{
 NSLog(@"Menu item B clicked");
}

-(void)MenuItemCClicked
{
  NSLog(@"Menu item C clicked");
}

//It's not mandatory for custom menu items

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{  
  if(action == @selector(MenuItemAClicked))
     return YES;
  else if(action == @selector(MenuItemBClicked))
    return YES;
  else if(action == @selector(MenuItemCClicked))
    return YES;
  else
    return NO;
}
```

view Controller header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController

@end
```

view Controller source file

```
 #import "ViewController1.h"
 #import "MenuControllerSupportingView.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()
{
 MenuControllerSupportingView *vu;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController1

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  vu=[[SGGI_MenuControllerSupportingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];

[self.view addSubview:vu];

 UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,200,30)];

 [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [btn setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(SHowMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [vu addSubview:btn];

}

-(void)SHowMenu
{
 UIMenuController *menucontroller=[UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

UIMenuItem *MenuitemA=[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A" action:@selector(MenuItemAClicked)];

UIMenuItem *MenuitemB=[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B" action:@selector(MenuItemBClicked)];

UIMenuItem *MenuitemC=[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"C" action:@selector(MenuItemCClicked)];

[menucontroller setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MenuitemA,MenuitemB,MenuitemC,nil]];

    //It's mandatory
[vu becomeFirstResponder];

    //It's also mandatory ...remeber we've added a mehod on view class
if([vu canBecomeFirstResponder])
{

    [menucontroller setTargetRect:CGRectMake(10,10, 0, 200) inView:vu];

    [menucontroller setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

}




-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

In View class if u write return YES alone in *canPerformAction* you will see all the default menuitems like camera symbol,cut,copy etc..

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
 return YES;
}
```

if u want to show something like camera alone then

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
if(action==@selector(_insertImage:))
     return YES;
else
     return NO;

}
```

if u want to know about all the actions then

visit the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html)

Comment: very helpful, I added similar code to subclass a UIButton in swift, and works like magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is having this issue specifically (and randomly) with iOS6: you might want to look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026309/168581) related to having Speak Selection enabled on the device (Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Speak Selection: On). A small number of my users were not able to see the custom `UIMenuItems` and this was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0 -

In my case I wanted to have the VC pre-select the text in a TextView and display a custom menu for the user to take action on that selection.  As mentioned by **Kalle**, order is very important, especially making `setMenuVisible` last.

In VC, `viewDidLoad`:

```
menuCont = UIMenuController.shared
let menuItem1: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Text", action: #selector(rtfView.textItem(_:)))
let menuItems: NSArray = [menuItem1]
menuCont.menuItems = menuItems as? [UIMenuItem]
```

In VC, when the user hits a button:

```
@IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(rangeStart, rangeLength)
    self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    menuCont.setTargetRect(CGRect.zero, in: self.textView)
    menuCont.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Finally, in the sub-class of the TextView:

```
class rtfView: UITextView {

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any!) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(textItem(_:))) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe because `CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 0, 0)` creates a `CGRect` with `width = 0` and `height = 0`?

cheers,
anka

Comment: Even if I set the width/height to something like 100, still doesn't show up.

Comment: Ok, you can try to add the method (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender and return YES.