# UIMenuController with UITableViewController doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to display `UIMenuController` when user selects any row in the table. I am using `UITableViewController` to display table with custom cell.

my code:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;

    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];

    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" action:@selector(action1:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item2" action:@selector(action2:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item3" action:@selector(action3:)];

    UIMenuController * menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    menuController.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuItem, menuItem1, menuItem2, nil];
    menuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;

    [menuController setTargetRect:cellFrame inView:self.view];

    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

But `UIMenuController` doesn't shown. Whats wrong in above code ?

Also, I've referred [these links](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?source=search_app#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=iphone%20sdk%20custom%20uimenucontroller&oq=iphone%20sdk%20uime&gs_l=hp.3.3.0i10i30l2j0i8i10i30j0i8i30.4787.73571.0.80474.15.11.0.4.4.0.542.2918.0j4j5j0j1j1.11.0.les;..0.0...1c.1._pDjOsKiASk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&fp=7cae748247176dd2&biw=1600&bih=720). But no luck.

Comment: hey bro.....refer this link if you have not..!!!http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/12/22/developers-notes-for-uimenucontroller#

Comment: See this, may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582116/copy-paste-functionality-in-uitableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with showing the menu only after a long press, there is no need to use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and show the menu yourself.

Instead, you can use this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

To hide the standard items (cut, copy, and paste), return NO here:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
```

Then you need to `return YES` from `canBecomeFirstResponder` like you have and, for some reason, I had to implement this method too:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Determine when a UIMenuController is dismissed?

Comment: This notifications ```[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willHideEditMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHideEditMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification object:nil];``` Not work using this delegates