# UIMenu buttons disappear after usage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I've customized UIMenuController like this:

```
UIMenuItem* note = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note action:@selector(noteItemTapped:)] autorelease];
UIMenuItem* share = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" action:@selector(shareItemTapped:)] autorelease]; 
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:note, share, nil]];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
```

and in UIWebView it work, but with some problems:
1) After some usings only default "Copy" button is shown
2) They don't on touch (I have a UITapGestureRecognizer added to my view) but if I touch and drag a little, they ok.

Can anyone provide me with some tutorials of such customizing or give some your suggestions about problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Stackoverflow Answer that should solve your problem:

[UIMenuController not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112925/uimenucontroller-not-showing-up)

Comment: Thanks, I solved it already and forgot about this topic. But it's a link to correct answer, thanks.