# UIMenuController not getting displayed

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I am displaying UIMenuController on long press & double tap gesture, but its not getting displayed. I have followed the answers given here  but it still not showing up. [UIMenuController not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112925/uimenucontroller-not-showing-up)

Below is my code

```
- (void) doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder]; 

    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:[gesture view]];
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DoubleTap" action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];

    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:resetMenuItem]];
    [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 0.0f, 0.0f) inView:[gesture view]];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void) longPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder]; 

    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:[gesture view]];
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"LongPress" action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];

    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:resetMenuItem]];
    [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 0.0f, 0.0f) inView:[gesture view]];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

I am trying to get this event on didSelectRow of tableView, What can be worng.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved my issue by adding below method in my code

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
     return YES; 
}
```

You must also implement the actions for all the buttons. Else that particular button wont be displayed in the menu.

Comment: anyone having previously working menus on iOS6 not working in iOS7?