# UIMenuController does not show after changing the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uimenucontroller

I have 2 viewControllers and in first one I'm using tapRecognizer to press and hold in order to show a UImenucontroller to copy a string. The tap is used for selecting the title on navigation bar, and it shows a UImenucontroller with copy item on it.

It works for the **first** time, but when user switch to another view controller and come back to the first view controller again, the menu does not show any more.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *viewWithTitleLabel = self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1];
    viewWithTitleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(topBarTitleTap:)];
    [viewWithTitleLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

-(void)topBarTitleTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX([self.view bounds]), -12.0, 0.0f, 0.0f) inView:self.view];
        [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) copy:(id) sender {
    // called when copy clicked in tab bar title
    NSString *copyStringverse = self.navigationItem.title;
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard setString:copyStringverse];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I tried your code it didn't work at all. If I pass something like 40 instead of -12 for the y value in the setTargetRect: method, it works every time even after going to another controller and coming back.

Comment: this view is a subview and is embedded in a navigational view controller, that's why I've added -12. And is in correct position when it shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [self becomeFirstResponder]; before pop UIMenuController
For example you can change your code as follow

```
-(void)topBarTitleTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX([self.view bounds]), -12.0, 0.0f,     0.0f) inView:self.view];
        [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And don't forget to implement

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    //Customize your action if statement here
    return YES;
}
```

For your viewcontroller

Answer (score -1):

Check if LongPressGestureRecognizer is working, every time.

I would place the gesturerecognizer code in viewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad, just to be safe

Comment: I have tested with putting NSLog in tapRecognizer and it works, but nothing appears on screen

Comment: See if this link makes any sense  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112925/uimenucontroller-not-showing-up?rq=1

Comment: I have tried all and it works before I switch to new controller