# UIMenuController is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to get UIMenuController to display a menu.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
commentCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[commentCell becomeFirstResponder];
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
if (menu.menuVisible) {
    return;
}
menu.menuItems = @[[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"copy" action:@selector(log)], [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"report" action:@selector(log)]];
const CGRect targetFrame = commentCell.frame;
const CGRect convertedFrame = [commentCell convertRect:targetFrame toView:self.viewController.view];
[menu setTargetRect:convertedFrame inView:self.viewController.view];
[menu update];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately, it seems that my menu is not displaying. I tried to follow the guidelines outlined in: [UIMenuController not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112925/uimenucontroller-not-showing-up) but I've already tried all the suggestions including making my view implement `canBecomeFirstResponder` and setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. Any ideas what might be the issue or how I can debug further?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. 
It turns out I needed to also include the field: `-(BOOL)canPerformAction` in `self.viewController`

Answer (score 0):

I want  to add an issue that the targetFrame should be:

`const CGRect targetFrame = commentCell.bounds;`