# Allow user to select text from UILabel to copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel, but how can I allow the user to select a portion of it's text. I don't want the user to be able to edit the text nor the label/textfield to have a border.

Comment: Use https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTCopyableLabel

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel/55805279#55805279

Comment: or ..https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541271/294884

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is not possible with `UILabel`.

You should use `UITextView` for that. Just disable editing using `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate method.

Comment: But that will have the 3D border doesn't it?

Comment: I used UITextField few week ago and I remember that there were no border (it was created in xib). If your UITextField has a border, then just read documentation to find out how to disable border.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone]

Comment: You mean UITextView not UITextField, right?  There is no `editable` property on UITextField.

Comment: Here is a category that does just that: https://github.com/alexandreos/UILabel-Copyable

Comment: Actually, it IS possible with any `UIResponder` subclass.

Answer (score 36):

You use create a UITextView and make its `.editable` to NO. Then you have a text view which (1) the user cannot edit (2) have no border and (3) the user can select text from it.

Answer (score 26):

A poor man's version of copy and paste, if you cannot, or don't need to use a text view, would be to add a gesture recognizer to the label and then just copy the entire text to the pasteboard. It's not possible to do just a portion unless you use a `UITextView`

Make sure you let the user know it's been copied and that you support both a single tap gesture as well as a long press, as it will pick up users trying to highlight a portion of text. Here is a bit of sample code to get you started:

Register the gesture recognizers on your label when you create it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textTapped:)];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textPressed:)];
                [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
                [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
                [myLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Next up handle the gestures:

```
- (void) textPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized &&
        [gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *someLabel = (UILabel *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteboard setString:someLabel.text];
        ...
        //let the user know you copied the text to the pasteboard and they can no paste it somewhere else
        ...
    }
}

- (void) textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized &&
        [gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *someLabel = (UILabel *)gestureRecognizer.view;
            UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
            [pasteboard setString:someLabel.text];
            ...
            //let the user know you copied the text to the pasteboard and they can no paste it somewhere else
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but you should add one line of code:  myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;