# Swift Error, UIMenuItem to UIview/UIlabel for Copy

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uimenuitem

I am having an issue in finding the UIview/Casting from UImenuItem and UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I can see the copy button but once i click i am having an error of casting.

**Below is My Code**

ViewDidLoad

```
 let copyLongPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(OfficeMapController.handleLongPress(_:)))

 self.addressView.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)



   func handleLongPress(longPressView :UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    becomeFirstResponder()
    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    let copyItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action:  #selector(OfficeMapController.copyText))
           menu.menuItems = [copyItem]

    menu.setTargetRect(CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50), inView: longPressView.view!)
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)


}
  override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

  func copyText(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let searchlbl = sender.view! as UIView
    print(searchlbl)
    //Than Label Value code for Copy

}
 override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    // You need to only return true for the actions you want, otherwise you get the whole range of
    //  iOS actions. You can see this by just removing the if statement here.

    if action == #selector(OfficeMapController.copyText) {

        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**ERROR BELOW**

```
  2016-05-20 16:59:40.428 [2732:1548168] -[UIMenuController view]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155507820
 2016-05-20 16:59:40.429 [2732:1548168] *** Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIMenuController view]:    unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155507820'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (0x180c3ae38 0x18029ff80 0x180c41ccc 0x180c3ec74 0x180b3cd1c 0x100183dbc    0x100183f10 0x18634638c 0x18634574c 0x181602628 0x180bf181c 0x180bf14c0   0x180beebd4 0x180b18d10 0x182400088 0x185dedf70 0x10019caa0 0x1806b68b8)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Could someone help me to find out solutions for below?

Comment: are you adding long press on webView or what ??

Comment: @RahulShirphule, No its a simple UIView

Comment: Actually I don't know how you are copying from UIView because  As per my understanding you can't copy content from UIView... for that you need have textview / webview ect which will support the select and copy functionality..!

Comment: here is the one example link which is copying text from webView     ` https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-custom-menus-using-uimenucontroller`

Comment: @RahulShirphule, Can we do it from UIlabel? One more thing i can't open your link

Comment: okay I edit my comment and no you can't copy it for UILabel also...see this  [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091053/allow-user-to-select-text-from-uilabel-to-copy)

Comment: please vote if it helps you..!!

Comment: Mate , It some of be some way. I can see some of the answers in Objective C but hard to find the answers in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel

Comment: I am just wondering , How it can be possible with Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Look at some tutorials and GitHub project below

1. [Copyable Label Tutorial Swift](http://stephenradford.me/make-uilabel-copyable/)
2. [GitHub CopyLabel Class swift](https://github.com/Antidote-for-Tox/Antidote/blob/master/Antidote/CopyLabel.swift)

And if you want to use some existing Objective C code into Swift code then use [This site](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) to convert Objective c to swift. it dose a good job.

Hope it help :)