# Copying a text from UILabel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a situation where i want to copy the text from UILabel as a default cut/copy menu which appears in iPhone.I know that i can use a UITextField for enabling this menu but the key pad pops up and when i make the editing to return no,the keypad is not showing up and the default copy/cut menu is also not showing up.

I tried to use UITextView and unchecked the diting property in the properties of the UITextView,but it didn't gave me a proper solution.Because when the font exceeds the UITextView's height. It goes to the next line and it cannot be aligned properly in a view which i have now.

I came across this post "[Show iPhone cut copy paste menu on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel)" in stack overflow itself which says the same functionality which I need.

I downloaded the source code from git but I got 23 errors.

How can  implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This github project is compiled fine and I have tested it it's working

[UILabel copy using menu](https://github.com/zoul/UILabel-Clipboard-Sample)

Comment: I also got no errors while compiling the project. It seems works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out [HTCopyableLabel](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTCopyableLabel) on GitHub.  It's a UILabel subclass that makes copying text easy.