# UITextView : Changing text colour modifies text position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview, uicolor

I've got a UITextView with a small text in it. It displays correctly with black text on white background. However, when I want to change the text colour to a colour other than black, the text position changes (as if there was an empty line added at the beginning of the text).

With no colour change or with `textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];` :

[image: correct displaying with black colour]

When I change to another colour, here `textView.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];` :

[image: incorrect displaying with any other colour]

**The code line I've given really is the only code element that changes**, and even if the colours in the background and the text are different, this is because they are generated randomly, in a complete other part of my code. The content of the text **NEVER** had any influence on the display before, and when I change the text colour it **ALWAYS** looks like in the 2nd picture.

I am stunned by this behaviour, as `textColor` shouldn't be modifying anything else than the font colour, should it ? Plus the fact that when I change to `blackColor`, no weird behaviour.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: What do you mean by "no weirt behaviour"? Does it change the position back as seen in the first screenshot or does it stay at the wrong position but changes to black?

Comment: And yes. Changes to the textColor property shoudl not change much but the colour. I am afraid that you must have made some other changes to the view or view hierarchy. Apparently you have not yet realized what that is. Go and look for it. You may want to NSLog the lable (or whatever view it is) object directly. It describes itself very well including text, colour and font (I think), position and size respectively its frame.

Comment: @HermannKlecker2: **without touching anything else**, if I comment this particular code line, it switches to correct behaviour (1st picture), and if I uncomment it then it behaves like in the 2nd picture. With NSLog, no font/colour info but frame is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: I think both text is different..That would be a bigger one from the first one.I think so.

Comment: @R.A and @Hermann: I've edited my question so that you understand why I'm sure that the line `textView.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];` is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`"the different colours in the background are generated somewhere else"` means
Where do you exactly change the colors?

You are changing some thing like

a)`autoresizing` the views (or)

b)`Aligning` text in that view (or)

c)`Frame` size of your textView can be smaller than the `font size` of your textview  (or)

d)your text would be `longer than actual size of the frame`.

I would like to ask you one question.
Why do you use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`??
I'm asking because textview will bring the `scrollview`, when the text is longer than your frame size.Probably that would be your problem I hope..

Comment: No autoresizing, no aligning, the frame size of my textView is big enough and anyway not changing (I tried increasing the textView width but it didn't solve the problem). 

Indeed, with a UILabel there seems to be no problem, but I cannot copy/paste the content of the label, can I ? Well, if I get no further explanation I'll probably end up using a UILabel, thank you for the tip...

Comment: Of course you can copy and paste from your UIlabel..I m sure.

Comment: Well, apparently you can't copy from a UILabel if you use it raw : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel. And I can't manage to make the textView scroll, but I can have the kind of magnifying glass appear and see the whole text.

Comment: Check @zoul answer in that question..I just did it and i works for him