# UILabel with UIMenuController - Copy text in UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uimenucontroller, uipasteboard

I've a `UILable` with text "This is label with `UIMenuController`". I've added `UILongPressGesture` on label and open `UIMenuController` from it.

Menu controller considers frame of `UILable` as a source view (as it's its natural behavior), but I want specific word on UILabel should become a source point of `UIMenuController` and copy the same word into `UIPaseBoard` area.

i.e.: If I tap/press on word 'label' in `UILabel` frame, then source point of `UIMenuController` should be word 'label' and it should get copied into `UIPasteboard`.

How can I achieve this.

**Hint:**
I visited this question, it considers whole text of UILabel and I need specific range of text on which user clicks (long press)

[Show iPhone cut copy paste menu on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel)

Here is ref, snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show iPhone cut copy paste menu on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246198/show-iphone-cut-copy-paste-menu-on-uilabel)

Comment: @davidethell I already visited that question and there is no answer that I need in my question. You can see that in my snapshot, I've already done that level of code

Comment: Well, the best answer is that you need to make it a UITextField and just turn off editing.

Comment: @davidethell I can't use textfield. It'll create more problems for me to handle textfileds events when textfields and such kind of labels are in Same screen. (view controller). And I need to implement this for all labels, in app. I must have to extend UILabel and find out solution of my problem. Pl. help to solve this issue with UILabel. Thanks for your advice.